# Where can I find a proof that a $C^*$-algebra is nuclear iff it has completely positive approximation property?

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras

Def1. A $C^*$-algebra is said to be nuclear, if for every $C^*$-algebra $B$, the $C^*$-norm on $A\otimes B$ is unique.

Def2. $A$ $C^*$-algebra is said to have completely positive approximation property, if there exists a net of finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras $F_\lambda$, with contractive completely positive linear maps $\varphi_\lambda:A\to F_\lambda$ and $\psi_\lambda:F_\lambda\to A$, such that

$$
(\psi_\lambda\circ \varphi_\lambda)(a)\to a
$$

holds pointwisely.

The only reference I can find is Christopher Lance's *On Nuclear $C^*$-Algebra* , where he showed type $I$ $C^*$-algebras and their inductive limits have completely positive approximation property. Where can I find a proof for the general case?

Comment: This was proved by Choi-Effros in 1979 but it was also proved by E. Kirchberg independently in 1977. The proof is hard and lengthy. The standard reference for this is Brown Ozawa, chapters 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent reference with (relatively) detailed proofs is:

> Nathanial P. Brown and Narutaka Ozawa. $C^∗$
> -algebras and finite-dimensional approximations. Vol. 88. Graduate Studies in Mathematics. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI,
> 2008, pp. xvi+509.

In particular, have a look at theorem 3.8.7.